# Ways to get strace-like output for Heisenbug

Tags: linux, polling, strace

I'm chasing a Heisenbug in a linux x64 process.  (Attaching to a the process with a debugger or strace makes the problem never occur.)  I've been able to put in an infinite loop when the code detects the fault and attach with gdb that way, but it just shows me that a file descriptor (fd) that should be working is no longer valid.  I really want to get a history of the fd, hence trying strace, but of course that won't let the problem repo.

Other factors indicate that the problem with gdb/strace is timing.  I've tried running strace with  `-etrace=desc` or even `-eraw=open` and outputting to a ramdisk to see if that would reduce the strace overhead in the right way to trigger the problem, but no success. I tried running strace+, but it is a good order of magnitude slower than strace.

The process I'm attaching to is partly a commercial binary that I don't have source access to, and partly code I preload into the process space, so `printf`-everywhere isn't 100% possible.

Do you have suggestions for how to trace the fd history?

**Update:** added note about strace+

Comment: Is the program multi-threaded? Perhaps that `fd` has been closed in some other thread....

Comment: It is, and that's another reason I'd really like the OS's perspective on what happened to the fd.

Comment: The right way to solve issues like this is to eliminate the possibility of the bug altogether. Refactor your code so that you have an single thread that "owns" a file that will be opening, reading, and closing the file directly, and that other threads can only request to read/write from a thread-safe queue (using locks/counting semaphore are another possibility, but queue is usually easier to write and safer).

Comment: @Lie Ryan: Which would be possible if I owned all the code, but in this case I only control the preloaded code, which is why I'm still trying to get suggestions on how to monitor the fd externally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the tracing problem by:

1. Preloading wrapper stub functions around the relevant system calls, `open()`, `close()` and `poll()`
2. Logging the relevant information in a filename created on a ramdisk.

(The actual issue was a race, with the kernel's `poll()` tring to access `pollfd` memory and returning `EFAULT`.)